# Extract pictures from a table in a PDF

Tags: image

I would like to write a small program, or script, to extract a set of pictures from a pdf.

I have several PDFs, they each have a table of pictures. I would link to have one picture per file. Therefore I need a way to extract them. Due to the nature of the PDF (A table/grid), it seems that it would be much easier to write a program, than do some manual method. However I have no idea what tools are available.

What libraries are available?

---

Preference Python, then C# or Java, then maybe some other language (My C and C++ is rusty, I have not done them for years).

I am on Debian Gnu/Linux, so have a wide choice of tools.

Comment: `pdfimages` from the Poppler package should do the trick.

Comment: Did you mean to post that on the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with pdfbox (an Apache project, so Free Software) it is a java library and a command line tool (the app module). I then scripted it with a bit of python to process the extracted text (yes it did that as well), and rename the image files.